# AngularJS: ng-pattern to check for integer input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I'm stumped by the following problem. I have the following html input using AngularJS:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="widgetQuantity" id="widgetQuantity"
ng-model="finalWidget.quantity" placeholder="Enter A Number" min="1" 
ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required/>

<p ng-show="widgetForm.widgetQuantity.$error.min" class="help-block">
You gotta order at least one.</p>

<p ng-show="widgetForm.widgetQuantity.$error.pattern" class="help-block">
No partial widgets, please.</p>
```

The ng-pattern directive catches the negative symbol and decimals, but it's not catching "e" input into the form. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: uhm i think you should use ngMessages to display and validate your forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `type="number"` requirement in the input field solved this issue -- apparently HTML validation will override errors from the angular side.